# there is no char between 2 group with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a regexp to filter a list of paths.

my sample list is below:

```
models/user.js
models/adapter.js
models/acquire.js
models/schema/extension.js
models/schema/permission.js
modules/breaktime/models/break.js
modules/breaktime/models/rule.js
modules/breaktime/models/step.js
modules/pbxmanager/models/group.js
modules/pbxmanager/models/member.js
modules/pbxmanager/models/shift.js
modules/breaktime/models/request.js
modules/breaktime/models/state.js
```

I'd define the exact start path and want to get only the files under that path, not from subfolders.

For example; if I set `models/` as a starter string in the regexp, I should only get first 3 line, not those under schema folder.

I tried to make groups like (^start string)(exactly nothing)(end string$) but no luck.

```
(^models\/)[\w{0}](\/[\w]+\.js$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wNtCni/1

I couldn't find how to set "nothing between two group" in regexp.

Comment: Do yo mean like this? `^models\/[^\/]+\.js$`  https://regex101.com/r/5DbDDJ/1 or using word chars `^models\/\w+\.js$`

Comment: this feels like using a hammer to drive in a screw: what are you _actually_ doing that requires going through a iist of lines at all? Where does that data come from and what you trying to use the result for?

Comment: thanks @Thefourthbird you rock!

Comment: you summarized my life well @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans :) I generate this list in the begining of app in order to ease acces. all of them are sequelize model files for public and dynamicly created schemas.  instead of import all models in controller, sync them in a loop! I just needed to filter right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a character class `[\w{0}]` there is at least a single char expected, either a word character, `{`, `0`, or `}`

In your case you don't want that and you can omit it the character class which will give you `(^models\/)(\/[\w]+\.js$)` which has a forward slash too much.

If you remove that extra `/` as well, and remove the unnecessary groups and brackets, you will get

```
^models\/\w+\.js$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FrJmlf/1)